# onclick print destination url

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a link on our invoices page.

The link, points to a print friendly url for printing the invoice.

The issue is, I would like to "onclick" print the content of that URL.
Not sure if this is dooable without opening the destination url first. Is it ?

Link: ( this first method doesnt work because it prints current URL )

```
<li class="print"><a href="https://www.mysite.com.au/pdf/invoice_parse.html?id=<?=$r['invoice'];?>" onClick="window.print();return false">Print Invoice</a></li>
```

Essentially, I want to onclick of the link, print the destination URL. Without leaving the page. Any suggestions please

Comment: You mean the content of the webpage that can be found via that URL. An URL is an address, not a page.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `window.print()`, it prints the current window. So you could open an `iframe` and then call `window.print()` inside of it.

You could probably get away with hiding the `iframe` by giving it `position: absolute; left: -9999px`.

#### JavaScript

Assuming these links [match on protocol, domain and host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

```
var printInvoice = function(url) {
    
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
        iframeDocument;

    iframe.style.postion = 'absolute';
    iframe.style.left = '-9999px';
    iframe.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    if ('contentWindow' in iframe) {
       iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow;
    } else {
       iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
    }
    
    var script = iframeDocument.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript';

    script.innerHTML = 'window.print();';

    iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

}
```

Untested, but it should work :)

Comment: This approach is worth a shot, inject an invisible iframe and call print() on its window object.

Comment: Yeah I had looked at that, but somewhat cumbersome. I was hoping to use something like onclick="window.location='URL'

Comment: @422 Something less cumbersome then inline event handlers? This is frontend web development, lots of things feel like a kludge. :)

Comment: @alex well we are loading the invoice within Modal window ( iframe ) not sure how and where to add your code, Would you be so kind as to knock up a fiddle please ?

Comment: @422 I can't knock up a fiddle because the fiddle runs from `fiddle.jsfiddle.com` and thus I can't inject code into it. I'll try something else though :)

Answer (score -1):

Just provide a link to the PDF and let your users print it from their favourite PDF viewer. Doing this sort of thing automatically is just annoying, and you won't find a decent way to do it anyway.

Comment: If that was the case, we would all use Internet explorer, and have huge print buttons everywhere. Not all users are savvy on the internet ( inc me at times ) And providing a automated system on page in our case makes sense. We have the Invoices as PDF's also, for them to click, open save print etc etc, just wanted an automated "on-page" option aswell.

Comment: @422: Then I'll settle for "you're killing the rainforests".